# Streamlit App Predictions Not Updating Despite User Input Changes

Tags: streamlit

I’m working on a breast cancer project. However, I’m having issues with my prediction on Streamlit. Whenever I click on the predict button, it shows the same prediction no matter the adjustments I make to the sliders.

Below is the code i'm running at the moment.

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pickle
import altair as alt
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu


X = np.load(r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\BreastCancerML_Folder\breast-cancer-diagnosis-ml\notebooks\features_matrix.npy")

# Loading the saved model
brCancer_model = pickle.load(open(r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\BreastCancerML_Folder\breast-cancer-diagnosis-ml\models\svm_model.sav", "rb"))

# Function to predict and return result
def predict_cancer(radius_mean, texture_mean, perimeter_mean,area_mean,smoothness_mean, compactness_mean, concavity_mean):
    
    input_data = np.array([[radius_mean, texture_mean, perimeter_mean,area_mean,smoothness_mean, compactness_mean, concavity_mean]])
    pred = brCancer_model.predict(input_data)[0]
    pred_prob = brCancer_model.predict_proba(input_data)[0]
    
    if pred == 1:
        return "There is a {:.2f}% chance that this patient has benign cancer (Cancerous).".format(pred_prob[1] * 100)
    else:
        return "There is a {:.2f}% chance that this patient has malignant cancer (Non Cancerous).".format(pred_prob[0] * 100)

# Streamlit app
st.title("Breast Cancer Prediction")

# Sidebar input
st.sidebar.header("User Input")
radius_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Radius Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 0])), float(np.max(X[:, 0])), float(np.mean(X[:, 0])))
texture_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Texture Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 1])), float(np.max(X[:, 1])), float(np.mean(X[:, 1])))
perimeter_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Perimeter Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 2])), float(np.max(X[:, 2])), float(np.mean(X[:, 2])))
area_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Area Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 3])), float(np.max(X[:, 3])), float(np.mean(X[:, 3])))
smoothness_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Smoothness Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 4])), float(np.max(X[:, 4])), float(np.mean(X[:, 4])))
compactness_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Compactness Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 5])), float(np.max(X[:, 5])), float(np.mean(X[:, 5])))
concavity_mean = st.sidebar.slider("Concavity Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 6])), float(np.max(X[:, 6])), float(np.mean(X[:, 6])))



# Predict button
if st.sidebar.button("Predict"):
    prediction_result = predict_cancer(radius_mean, texture_mean,perimeter_mean,area_mean,smoothness_mean,compactness_mean,concavity_mean)
    st.write("Prediction Result:")
    st.write(prediction_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of your variable that is used inside a new block (`with` statement, `if` statement, etc.), you have to use the `session_state` to keep their values into memory.
Example:

```py
st.session_state["radius_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Radius Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 0])), float(np.max(X[:, 0])), float(np.mean(X[:, 0])))
st.session_state["texture_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Texture Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 1])), float(np.max(X[:, 1])), float(np.mean(X[:, 1])))
st.session_state["perimeter_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Perimeter Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 2])), float(np.max(X[:, 2])), float(np.mean(X[:, 2])))
st.session_state["area_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Area Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 3])), float(np.max(X[:, 3])), float(np.mean(X[:, 3])))
st.session_state["smoothness_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Smoothness Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 4])), float(np.max(X[:, 4])), float(np.mean(X[:, 4])))
st.session_state["compactness_mean"] = st.sidebar.slider("Compactness Mean", float(np.min(X[:, 5])), float(np.max(X[:, 5])), float(np.mean(X[:, 5])))
```

Please see tutorials and explanations [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/session-state) and [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state).